# dataTask in networking is not executing

Tags: swift, combine

In RestManager class, using URLSession I want to return *AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never>*.

So I made this code

```
class RestManager {

func fetchData<T: Decodable>(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never> {
    
    return Future<Result<T, ErrorType>, Never> { promise in
        URLSession
            .shared
            .dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                    if let data = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!){
                        promise(.success(.success(data)))
                    }else {
                        promise(.success(.failure(.empty)))
                    }
                }
                else if let error = error as? URLError {
                    switch error.code {
                    case .notConnectedToInternet, .networkConnectionLost, .timedOut:
                        promise(.success(.failure(.noInternetConnection)))
                    case .cannotDecodeRawData, .cannotDecodeContentData:
                        promise(.success(.failure(.empty)))
                    default:
                        break
                }
                }else {
                    promise(.success(.failure(.general)))
                }
            }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

But when I call this function in viewModel it returns empty array, but there is not any error thrown.
I used breakpoints on *if* and *else* statements and program is actually not executing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard `dataTask` of `URLSession` must be *resumed*

```
URLSession
    .shared
    .dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

       ...

    }
    .resume()
```

An alternative is Combine's `.dataTaskPublisher(for`